# Bump map not applying at all

Tags: texturing, normals, texture-painting, normal-map

I've been trawling through the web for 2+ hours on this issue, determined to find the answer instead of creating a new thread - but I can't seem to find a solution that will work for me at all.

I've applied a normal map to the plane that acts as a table, but no matter what I do I cannot get it to raise up or down. I've attached both a screenshot from the 3d viewport + node view, and the final render as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

P.S I've been following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izqZe8s_Jmw

[image]

[image: 3D Viewport and Node View]

[image: Final Render]

Comment: can you share the normalmap?

Comment: I'm unsure if this is what you meant - https://imgur.com/a/duWw6 - if not I'll do my best if you explain it. Cheers!

Comment: The Normalmap is the map you see in the middle of this image. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping#/media/File:Normal_map_example_with_scene_and_result.png
Can you show what image you plugged in the second image texture slot in your Material (the one which goes into the normal Map Node).

Normal map and Bump map are two different concepts

Comment: Looking at your node setup, the Texture for the diffuse color should NOT be set to non-color data, but "Color". Also, are you using a bump map (greyscale) or a normal map (purple-colored)? (as already asked by @monatsed) Those have to be treated differently.

Comment: michaelh thankyou, I am using a normal map (purple-colored). @monatsend I managed to get that view of my plane - it was a flat blue surface. I can upload another picture if it doesn't violate the forum rules

Comment: yes you can add more pictures to your post, but I would recommend that you append a .blend file (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). and don't forget to pack the textures in the file. 
If you dont want to share your files, just create dummys. The only important part is your normal / bump map and the Material.

Comment: @monatsend Thanks for offering to take a look. I've edited the post with my blend file :-)

Comment: The problem is with the normal map it self. For some reason its not the correct one to use... It is compressed and generates unwanted stepping. You should download correct diffuse and normal maps (don't use printscreen or similar).

Comment: Yes. Your normal map is completely useless. There are only some artefacts on the map. It is otherwise completely empty. (i.e. a solid color without variation) You should be able to see faint lines similar to your wood texture.

Comment: You guys are great, thanks for letting me know and being able to identify the issue so promptly. +1 to you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really plug your normal map into both the Diffuse and Glossy node, however, that's not why you are seeing no effect.

The normal map you are using is basically flat. You can see this by looking at it in the UV Image Editor. It's from a glossy surface with virtually no variations in surface depth. You will simply not see much, if any, effect from that normal map.

To contrast, look at the normal map you are using (basically all one colour) and then look at this (randomly selected) one I found on Google from a brick surface that has a lot of variation: http://jsoverson.github.io/texture.js/demo/images/brickwork-normal.jpg

Comment: +1, not enough rep to do any more. Thanks for the advice on both counts. After plugging your brick wall map in it's clearly working.

Comment: No problem. Yes, there is nothing wrong with your setup as such. Just that normal map is from a basically flat, polished surface so... no bumps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a quick Normal map from your Image texture. try this tool. It is very basic but you can use it for free.

http://www.smart-page.net/smartnormal/

just open your texture from you disc via the load button. and increase or decrease your Bias.

If your normal seems to point in the wrong direction, just pick "flip green channel"

[image]

Comment: Another very handy comment. Monatsend you helped me through the intial part, so I wish I could select two correct answers. That tool is extremely helpful and got me a very nice finish with the texture I used.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you. ;-)